# How to define automatically a unique object/symbol name based on a type

Tags: c++

I am looking for a way to define automagically a unique object/symbol name based on a type, like illustrated in the following example, where `MEMBER(TypeName)` is something (macro/whatever...) that represents/expands to a unique object identifier, which identifier is defined from `TypeName`.

```
class A { int i; };
class B { int i; };
class X
{
    A MEMBER(A);
    B MEMBER(B);
    X()
    {
        MEMBER(A).i = 1;
        MEMBER(B).i = 2;
    }
};
```

I first tried using the following simple macro to do this:

```
#define MEMBER(TypeName)    m_ ## TypeName
```

which works great, as long as `TypeName` is not a fully qualified name such as `NameSpace::Type`; so I am still looking for a solution working with fully qualified type names.

Note1: the syntax for definition and use of members of class `X` described above is given only to clarify my needs; the solution may involve a totally different way to define and use the members.
Note2: members of class `X` must not be static.
Note3: access to members within class `X` must be fast; a compile-time solution is preferable.
Note4: class `X` cannot contain more than one member of the same type.

Thanks for help.

Comment: how about using `std::tuple` ? if you are generating names based on types, then it means your class members have unique types. If that is so, then `std::tuple::get<TYPENAME>` is perfect for you.
Preprocessor macros should be avoided in C++, unless it cannot be in C++.

Comment: @mariusm: Sounds like a good solution to my problem. I'll give it a try and post my feedback. Please post your solution as an answer so that it can get votes. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @mariusm: after a quick look, std::tuple could be a good solution if std::tuple::get<TypeName> is resolved at compile time (performance penalty would not be acceptable if not); can you tell me if it is resolved at compile time or not ? thanks.

Comment: `std::get<TYPE>` is resolved at compile time. sometimes that is a benefit, sometimes it is a limitation.

Comment: @mariusm: yes, it is indeed resolved at compile time, and that is exactly what I need; I thus used this(your) solution in my code, and got rid of macros; one drawback of this solution though: it requires C++14 compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If names are a hassle then let's get rid of them completely using tuples:

```
#include <tuple>

class A: public std::tuple<int>{};
class B: public std::tuple<int>{};

class X: std::tuple<A,B> {
public:
   X() {
     std::get<int>(std::get<A>(*this)) = 1;
     std::get<int>(std::get<B>(*this)) = 2;
   }
};
```

Comment: only drawback that I see is you still have to name the types... ;)

Comment: Actually, classes A & B are far more complex than presented above, so I have to keep them as there are. However, I definitely can use std::tuple to store A & B instances into X. Something like <code>class X { std::tuple<A,B> inst; }</code>. Then I can access to instances within X using std::get<A>(inst) (which is resolved at compile time and thus fast, as required). Now I have to solve a new problem which is: A & B have no default constructor. Thank you very much for your solution, it looks like a very good (if not the best) one.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios there is also `std::get<N>()` variant with N as const integer, which provides access to each individual field in the tuple.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `__LINE__` marco as a mix part in your marco:

> `__LINE__`
>   This macro expands to the current input line number, in the form of a decimal integer constant. While we call it a predefined macro, it's a pretty strange macro, since its “definition” changes with each new line of source code.

Comment: I guess it wouldn't work if two declarations were in the same line

Comment: It seems to me there is no such requirement, but `__LINE__` is supported everythere because this is standard marco.

Comment: This solution indeed allows to define a unique symbol name at instance definition (as long as 2 definitions are not on the same line), but the main problem is: how to access the members later ? (like in the X() constructor in the example above). Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: Some compilers have a `__COUNTER__` macro for that purposes.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define DECL_NMEMBER(NameSpace, TypeName) NameSpace::TypeName m_##NameSpace##_##TypeName;
#define NMEMBER(NameSpace, TypeName) m_##NameSpace##_##TypeName
#define DECL_MEMBER(TypeName) DECL_NMEMBER(, TypeName)
#define MEMBER(TypeName) NMEMBER(, TypeName)

namespace N 
{
class A { public: int i; };
class B { public: int i; };
}

class C { public: int i; };

class X
{
    DECL_NMEMBER(N, A)      // N::A
    DECL_NMEMBER(N, B)      // N::B
    DECL_MEMBER(C)          // C
    DECL_NMEMBER(std, string)   // std::string
    DECL_MEMBER(wstring)    // std::wstring (using namespace std)
    X()
    {
        NMEMBER(N, A).i = 1;
        NMEMBER(N, B).i = 2;
        MEMBER(C).i = 5;
        NMEMBER(std, string) = "test";
        MEMBER(wstring) = L"test2";
    }
};
```

but for some types like `vector<T>` you need make some additional macros(
there are no perfect solution I guess

Comment: Thanks, it's an acceptable workaround for my current needs. Until I have to work with templated types, I am going to use your solution. Thanks for your answer.